# Embed more than 1 shiny application in Rmarkdown using shinyAppDir

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown, shiny-server

I want to embed two separate shiny apps in rmarkdown. Where should I put the `rmd` file?

When I only had one shiny app, I put the rmd in the directory as the shiny app and it worked.  The codes are as below:

````
```{r, echo=FALSE}
shinyAppDir(
 "E:/example/shinyfolder",
  options=list(
    width="100%", height=550
  )
)

```
````

But when I move the `rmd` to a upper level of shiny app folder, say, `E:/example` and use the exact absolute path as I used before, the error said `cannot open compressed file './Data/joined1.rda', probable reason 'No such file or directory'`, My idea is put the `rmd` in the upper level folder and reference the different apps in subfolders. Any idea about how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

This is probably related to your use of relative paths within your shiny application. Since I assume `joined1.rda` is a data file one of your shiny apps tries to read in, it cannot find it anymore as soon as the shiny app files (`server.R` and `ui.R`) are no longer in the same folder as your markdown file. Use paths relative to the path of your markdown file or explicitly set one with `setwd()`, either in your markdown file or within the app(s).

Assuming a folder/file structure like this...

```
/parentDir        (markdown.rmd)
    /apps
       /app1      (server.R, ui.R)
       /app2      (server.R, ui.R)
          /data   (joined1.rda)
```

...and further assuming your working directory is `~/parentDir` you can embed your shiny applications with `shinyAppDir(".apps/app1")` and `shinyAppDir("./apps/app2")`, respectively.

Within your shiny applications (`server.R`) you also either use absolute paths to your `/data` folder (if you really want to use absolute paths at all...), or you use relative paths according to your working directory. So if the second shiny app (in `/app2`) loads data from your `/data` folder, you use `load("./apps/app2/data/joined1.rda")`.